# How are declarative distros different than Kickstart?

Tags: configuration-management

[NixOS and GuixSD both bill themselves as "declarative" and DevOps-friendly.](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/1749/are-nixos-and-guixsd-the-incoming-linux-distros-of-devops) How and in what ways are these declarative distros different than Kickstart and/or a Linux distro managed by a configuration management tool?

What advantages and/or disadvantages are there to this style of declarative linux configuration as opposed to these currently existing technologies?

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK Kickstart is only usable for the initial installation of the OS, but not for subsequent package maintenance upgrades/downgrades.

Unless I miss something (quite possible, I don't have much experience w/ them) the Linux distros managed by configuration management tools require a minimum level of health from the OS (and some package requirements, at least in some cases) to be able to operate those tools, say to perform a rollback. At least NixOS appears to not have such requirement (or rather it is already fullfilled at the OS level). From [About NixOS](https://nixos.org/nixos/about.html):

> Rollbacks
>
> Because the files of a new configuration don’t overwrite old ones, you
>   can (atomically) roll back to a previous configuration. For instance,
>   if after a nixos-rebuild switch you discover that you don’t like the
>   new configuration, you can just go back:
>
> ```
> $ nixos-rebuild switch --rollback
> ```
>
> In fact, all old system configurations automatically show up in the
>   [Grub boot menu](https://nixos.org/nixos/screenshots/nixos-grub.png). So if the new configuration crashes or doesn’t
>   boot properly, you can just roll back by selecting an older
>   configuration in the Grub boot menu. Rollbacks are very fast: it
>   doesn’t involve lots of files having to be restored from copies.

Answer (score 3):

**Pros:**

1. No configuration management tools like puppet, chef, salt or ansible needed

**Cons:**

1. **Dependent:** If one has written a lot of [NixOps](https://nixos.org/nixops/) files and one decides to go to another provider then one has to rewrite all the provision scripts, while a tool like terraform is cloud agnostic
2. No autoscaling like docker
3. Promotion of silos, e.g. `DevOps friendly`. In my opinion dev should release software as well. Now one could just use docker that they use in development as well.

Comment: You do not need configuration management tools with kickstart. I am building AMI using Puppet and then final configuration is simple sh script.